# Why is SSIS ignoring the last column of my import from an Excel source?

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, ssis

I'm a business intelligence development intern, so please forgive me if I am not as versed as some in SQL or the Microsoft BI Stack.

I'm trying to import data from an Excel file (.xls) to an SQL Server database table, and for some reason the connection manager is ignoring the last column of my data entirely.

To make matters stranger, SSIS DOES read the data if I try to set up the connection manager within SSIS while the Excel file is open in Excel.
(I think I did this unintentionally at first, and was surprised by the result.)

Here is a preview of data without the file open in Excel:

[image]

And a preview of data with the file open before setting up the connection manager in SSIS:

[image]

Both of these depict the end of the data within the file, but for some reason as you can see, the 'Zone' column is omitted in the first data preview.

Steps I've tried so far:

1. Converting to a .csv file using a script task
2. Using an ADO.Net source and reading the excel data that way
3. Using an SQL command to view data rather than select from table or sheet
4. Changing the OpenRowset property to specify columns

Specifics about the source files:

1. First 3 rows of data are empty (except an image)
2. Row 4 contains header data
3. 'Zone' column is formatted as general, as is every other column that does not contain a date

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate the feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you reading the whole excel sheet or are you using a selected range e.g. `SELECT * FROM [MyWorksheet$B5:J100] `?

Comment: I've tried both, and neither avails me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SSIS has trouble detecting the datatype for a given column.  This can lead to unexpected NULLs.  Adding IMEX=1 to the ConnectionString can clear this fault.

Example
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your_Workbook.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=NO;";

becomes

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your_Workbook.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=NO;**IMEX=1**";

For more details see this blog post (not my own work):

http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/05/15/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: It's not so much the data type, as SSIS not detecting the column at all. As you can see in one example, Bill to Account is the last column, but in the other example, and in the actual file, Zone is the last column.

Comment: Sorry I can't see the examples, my firewall is blocking them.  I've tried to reproduce, but cannot create the same error.